# show several Toast with delay in service

Tags: android

I want to when user click on button, start a Service.
When the service starts .
I want to show 5 times text
The delay time is 3 seconds .

```
      show_toast1-------delay 3secounds ,
      show_toast2-------delay 3secounds,
      show_toast3-------delay 3secounds,.......
```

but when click on button Delay only occurs once!
and  other show_toast is displayed without delay

java code :

```
public class MyService extends Service {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "show_toast"+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    }
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return START_STICKY;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Handler instead if Thread.sleep() , Try the code below will work for you.

```
public Handler handler; //global
int i = 0;              //global

final Handler handler = new Handler(); 

    runable = new Runnable() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            try{
                //do your code here
                if(i < 4){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "show_toast"+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    i = i + 1;
                    //also call the same runnable 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                }
                else{
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runable);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        } 
    }; 
    handler.postDelayed(runable, 5000);
```